# Jipster Client Only App Error Non-abstract class 'AuthExpiredInterceptor'

Tags: jhipster

Hi I'm trying to install a client only version of jhipster.

I have used the following commands:

```
yo jhipster:client through yarn
```

but no luck, same with:

```
yo jhipster:client --npm --auth
```

and I still get the same error.

The server side generates fine but the client side is causing problems.

I'm on node: v7.7.1

> 

```html
   
ERROR in [at-loader] src/main/webapp/app/blocks/interceptor/auth-expired.interceptor.ts:6:14
    TS2515: Non-abstract class 'AuthExpiredInterceptor' does not implement inherited abstract member 'responseIntercept' from class 'HttpInterceptor'.

ERROR in [at-loader] src/main/webapp/app/shared/login/login.service.ts:12:37
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'AuthServerProvider'.

ERROR in [at-loader] src/main/webapp/app/shared/shared.module.ts:10:5
    TS2305: Module '"/Volumes/Flux/jhipster/src/main/webapp/app/shared/index"' has no exported member 'AuthServerProvider'.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/index.html] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/index.html 1.21 kB {0} [built]

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/Charlie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.1/bin/node" "/Users/Charlie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.1/bin/npm" "run" "webpack:build"
npm ERR! node v7.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! jhipster@0.0.0 webpack:build: `webpack --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js && webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the jhipster@0.0.0 webpack:build script 'webpack --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js && webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the jhipster package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js && webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs jhipster
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls jhipster
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Volumes/Flux/jhipster/npm-debug.log

npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.9 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.4.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.9 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.9 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/Charlie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.1/bin/node" "/Users/Charlie/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.1/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! jhipster@0.0.0 postinstall: `node node_modules/pngquant-bin/lib/install.js && node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js && npm run webpack:build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the jhipster@0.0.0 postinstall script 'node node_modules/pngquant-bin/lib/install.js && node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js && npm run webpack:build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the jhipster package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node node_modules/pngquant-bin/lib/install.js && node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js && npm run webpack:build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs jhipster
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls jhipster
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Volumes/Flux/jhipster/npm-debug.log

Client application generated successfully.

Start your Webpack development server with:
```

Answer (score 4):

found it:

```
yo jhipster:client --auth jwt
```

the --help flags are not well documented for auth types but works though